# Configuring postfix for forwarding rejected emails

Tags: postfix

Postfix has the rule smtpd_client_restrictions called `reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname`. It has good ability to reject spam. But some times there are IP address which don't have reverse zone and emails from such IP address are not a spam thus I come across with the negative reaction from customers who don't get email.

Is it possible to configure Postfix so emails that fall under that rule will not be rejected. Instead of this, such emails will be forwarded to the special mailbox.

Whitelisting is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reject AND forward to another mailbox, then you can't do that. For explanation see [Postfix - how to redirect email after they are rejected?](https://serverfault.com/questions/399098/postfix-how-to-redirect-email-if-they-will-rejecting). Otherwise see answer below.

**You can't do that with postfix alone**. Postfix only define **reject** action when client IP address fall into `unknown_reverse_client_hostname` criteria

As alternative you can use [postfwd](http://postfwd.org/) for policy server addon in postfix. Based on [this thread](http://www.engardelinux.org/modules/index/list_archives.cgi?list=postfix-users&page=0121.html&month=2013-05), you can use something like this on postfwd.

```
id=COMBO01 
    reverse_client_name==unknown 
    action=REDIRECT forwardingaddress@example.com
```